# QT/C++ - How to forward the status of a bool from mainwindow.cpp to a different class?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm a beginner to both C++ and Qt, and I know my question is trivial. But I somehow don't understand how to connect SIGNAL and SLOT when they belong to two different classes. I have in mainwindow.ui a QAction object "actionDebug_mode" which sets in mainwindow.cpp among others "m_debugMode = true".

```
void MainWindow::on_actionDebug_mode ()
{
    m_debugMode = true;
}
```

Now I need the bool "m_debugMode" also in "Logging.cpp" to switch something else there.

```
void Logging::method_ABC ()
{
if (m_debugMode) { ... }
}
```

So in the end I only need to get the state of "m_debugMode" (true/false) transferred from mainwindow.cpp to Logging.cpp. What is the easiest way to realize this?
Do I also need to create a method in Logging.cpp so that I can connect void MainWindow::on_actionDebug_mode () to it? Or is there an easier way?

Which code do I have to put into mainwindow.cpp, mainwindow.h, Logging.cpp and Logging.hpp? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Place the following in the Logging.cpp and call `setDebugMode` from `mainwindow.cpp`. Do not forget to add function signatures to `Logging.hpp`.

```cpp
static bool g_debugMode = false;

void setDebugMode(bool value) {
  g_debugMode = value;
}

bool getDebuggingMode() {
  return g_debugMode;
}
```

Comment: With that code I am getting the following errors:  
error: 'bool {anonymous}::getDebuggingMode()' defined but not used [-Werror=unused-function]
   bool getDebuggingMode()
error: 'void {anonymous}::setDebugMode(bool)' defined but not used [-Werror=unused-function]
   void setDebugMode(bool value)
What must I put into mainwindow.cpp?

Comment: @Urbi Use `getDebuggingMode() in your `Logging.cpp` or add `[[maybe_unused]] ` before the function in `Logging.hpp` if you are using C++17 or newer standard.